# How to redirect In symfony, how to redirect after authentication, on the URL before authentication?

Tags: php, symfony

I want a user to login (login page) and be redirected to the page on which they were before authentication.

For information, I created the login page using the `make:auth`-command and the redirection (in the code) is done in this code in the `AppAuthenticator`-class:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('page_to_redirect'));
}
```

Comment: This code is in the file AppAuthenticator.php

Comment: Here is the problem: I want a user to login (login page), and be redirected to the page on which it was before authentication. For information, I created the login page using the "make: auth" utility. And the redirection (in the code) is done in the code above

Comment: I would like to put in page_to_redirect, the value of the route before login

Comment: @VincentFritz  but onAuthenticationSuccess fucntion call when you authentciate sucessfully. it will never call before login.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a GuardAuthenticator. In that case you can use the [`TargetPathTrait`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Util/TargetPathTrait.php) to get the target path from the session.

```php
use TargetPathTrait;

...

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->session, $providerKey);

    return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
}
```

You might also want to provide a fallback, e.g. back to the homepage or read the info from another location, e.g. from an additional url query-parameter that you can set or you could also read it from the header, if you [enable `use_referer` in your firewall](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#using-the-referring-url).

Since the target path is not a route name, you don't need to use the UrlGenerator to retrieve the path for that route name.

Answer (score 0):

And thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, but I got another problem. In fact I found the solution:
When I enter the controller (before login), I store the route to redirect in the session:

```
>     /**
>      * @Route("/blog", name="blog")
>      */
>     public function blog(Request $request)
>     {
>         $request->getSession()->set("referer","blog");
>         return $this->render('main/blog.html.twig', [
>             'controller_name' => 'MainController',
>         ]);
>     }
```

And in the AppAuthenticator.php, I get the data using the referer :

> ```
> public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey) {
>     $url = $request->getSession()->get('referer');
>     return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate($url));
>
> }
> ```